# Get a segment of a Direct Byte/Short/Int/Float Buffer

Tags: java

What is the best way to substract a range of elements from one buffer to another with *independent* content?
Like this:

```
//before
DirectByteBuffer 1: (1, |2, 3, 4|, 5, 6) //get element range from 1 to 3

//after
DirectByteBuffer 1: (1, 5, 6)
DirectByteBuffer 2: (2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: you can use buffer.duplicate() to create a second copy, then prune the two buffers as desired. Not the answer you're looking for, but I don't know any methods that let you splice buffers.

Comment: does it have to be fast? if not you can use `List.subList` plus a copy operation to create the 2nd buffer and then `List.removeAll` to remove the extracted values from the first (if there's no duplicates)

Comment: You shouldn't really be using buffers for set operations in the first place. That's not what they're for.

Comment: You can blame me, but yes, it have to be fast. That's why it is buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`put(ByteBuffer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) should be the fastest way to copy bytes between buffers. So you can use this to copy part of one buffer into another buffer. Using different slices, you can also use this to move data within a single buffer, thus filling the “hole” left by the copied data. The basic steps are

1. Prepare a [new slice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice%28%29) for the source region
2. Set its [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28int%29) and [limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit%28int%29) to denote the data you want to copy
3. Set the [position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28int%29) in the destination buffer to where you want to put the data
4. Put the source slice at the destination position using [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29)

Comment: I was thinking about sharing data more than copying, because I've heard a lot about how complicated is GC-ing native buffers, and If I would copy the data, something can get "stuck" in the memory. I'm just trying to be careful and not to waste much RAM. Anyway, your solution is the only I can come up to, so I'll stick to that.